# pandas: remove the "," on the columns beginning when I save a Dataframe with .to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm saving my csv without errors with pandas but I have a problem on my columns name, there is a "," that I want to remove !

```
import pandas as pd
csv_path = "your\csv\path\and\filename.csv"
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'filename': [], 'words': []})
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=csv_path,index=False)
```

[image: Visual_on_the_problem]

I have `,filename,words` but I just want `filename,words`

Comment: Odd, since you do have `index=False` in `to_csv()`, which should definitely prevent that initial comma (i.e., an empty column header name). Do double check that you don't have an old file open somehow.

Comment: cannot reproduce on pandas 1.2.4, which version are you using?

Comment: pandas version: 1.3.4

Comment: Not reproducible with Pandas 1.3.4. See my answer. Try to print on `stdout`

Comment: I downgraded to 1.3.3, doesn't work too :/ I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is right for Pandas 1.3.4:

```
# df = pd.DataFrame(data={'filename': [], 'words': []})
>>> print(df.to_csv())
,filename,words

>>> print(df.to_csv(index=False))
filename,words
```

Comment: My apologizes, I found out that it was coming from somewhere else.